# How to confirm a user by clicking a link in Java Fx

Tags: java, email

I am trying to confirm a user through a link that was sent via email through JavaFX. However, I am not sure this is possible and I am open to other suggestions on how this can be done.

For some background context: we are trying to sign up a user for group/goal notifications in a fitness application. The admin will send a request for a user to join their group. The user will receive a mail, the user will click the link to return to the application and then accept the invitation.

```
  import java.io.File;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;
    import javax.activation.*;
    import java.awt.Desktop;
    import java.net.URI;
    
    public class SendMail {
        public static void sendMail(String receipient, String groupName) throws MessagingException {
    
            String appSender = "team1.5healthtracker@gmail.com";
            String password = "ganttsucks123";
    
            //String Usersender=User.INSTANCE.getEmail();
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                    "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    
    
            //get Session
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(appSender, password);
                        }
                    });
            //compose message
    
            Message message = prepareMessage(session, appSender, receipient, groupName);
            Transport.send(message);
        }
      private static Message prepareMessage(Session session, String appSender, String receipient,String groupName){
            try{
                //String groupMessage="<h1> Invitation to join group </h1> <p> You are  invited to join the group of <p1> "+ User.INSTANCE.getUsername()+"<p1> If you wish to join the group kindly click <a>Yes</a>. If not don't click anythting and ignore the message</p1>";
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);    //Create a message object
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(appSender));    //Set the sender
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(receipient));  //Set the recepient
                message.setSubject("Invitation to "+ User.INSTANCE.getUsername()+"'s Group");  //Create the subject
                //message.setContent(message, groupMessage);
                //message.setText("You are invited to join "+ User.INSTANCE.getUsername()+"'s Group"+" called: " +groupName+" If you accept to join please send a reply to this mail, confirming so other wise ignore this message");  //Create the message
                // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
                message.setContent(
                        "<h1> Invitation to join group </h1> <p1> You are  invited to join the group of </p1> "+ User.INSTANCE.getUsername()+" namely: " + groupName + " If you wish to join the group kindly click <a href='confirmation.html'>Yes</a>. If not don't click anythting and ignore the message</p1></h1>",
                        "text/html");
                System.out.println("Email has been sent successfully");
                System.out.println(message.getReplyTo().toString());
                return message;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
    
    
            }
    
    return null;
      }

  /*
  public static boolean ConfirmEmail(Session session, String[] appSender, String receipient,String groupName) throws MessagingException {
      Message message = new MimeMessage(session);    //Create a message object
      Desktop d =Desktop.getDesktop();
      d.browse(new URI());
  }

   */

}
```

Comment: don't see any relation to javafx, so removed the tag (feel free to re-add with a detailed explanation on how it indeed is related :)

Comment: You should change the password of your gmail Account ASAP